# how to make my webpage such that if anyone closes it, then next time when he opens it should start from the same page

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Code for webpage such that if anyone closes it, then next time when he opens it should start from the same page.

Thank you for giving your time.

Comment: speaking of which, what if you accidentally logged the last location of the user like, say.. logout.php? XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rough idea:
Set a cookie on each page they visit. Then call that page on the index for example.

On the page they enter

```
<?php
setcookie("page", "home.php", time()+3600);
?>
```

On any page i.e. index.php

```
if (isset($_COOKIE["page"])){
  header('Location: ' . $_COOKIE['page']);
}else{
   //do nothing or something
}
```

With the above solution gotta make sure that they are not redirected on every page but only when they revisit the website :)

Comment: You need to set cookie only after page close and remove cookie after redirection otherwise it'll be dead end.

Comment: @akshay1728 np... check the comment from PHPConnect... if you always set and get the cookie on everypage incorrectly.. you'll always be redirected to the same page :) gonna have to give it a little think on how the lifecycle of these cookies are gonna be

Comment: @Stevanicus: or only do this on index.php and not the home link of index2.php

Comment: You could use the same trick as mobile detection, if the 'HTTP_REFERRER' is not from the current website, you make the redirection (if the user manipulate his headers, screw him)

Answer (score 2):

you can use the following to track the last page visited by the user:

- cookies
- database

implementation depends on how you do your website. it's just a few tools that can get it working.

Answer (score 0):

lookup HTML5 localstorage, state management, and cookies as mentioned.